# Opencart Checkout issue 2.0.2.0

Tags: html, css, opencart, checkout, opencart2.x

Afternoon all,

I have a problem which i have never come across via opencart, The Version 2.0.2.0 and registered guests only. The problem starts when you register and purchase an item, When in the checkout, There is no Continue button after entering your Address. When you go on guest checkout its fine,

Our web address is www.vape-ashworths.co.uk thank you

Steven

Comment: So we have to register with your site and then buy something to reproduce this problem? Please provide a simpler way of demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @rghome unfortunatly that is the problem, when buying as a guest it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You have given `clearfix` class to the div that contains buttons. 
Remove the `clearfix`, it has `display:none`.

By the way same problem applies to registration form.

```
<div class="buttons clearfix">
  <div class="pull-right">I have read and agree to the <a href="http://www.vape-ashworths.co.uk/index.php?route=information/information/agree&amp;information_id=3" class="agree"><b>Privacy Policy</b></a> &nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1">
    <input type="button" value="Continue" id="button-register" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary">
  </div>
</div>
```

remove the clearfix from above code.